# How to implement Partial ordered Planning using #java using pop algorithm?

Tags: java

```
function POP1(π(= (A, L, ≺, B)), agenda) returns a plan
```

if (agenda = ∅) then return π.
    Select any pair (ai , pi ) and remove it from agenda.
 achievers ←− the set of operators achieving (ai , pi ).
    If achievers = ∅ return failure.
    Nondeterministically choose some operator aj ∈ achievers.
    pi L←−L∪{⟨aj −→ai⟩}.
    Update ≺ with aj ≺ ai.
    Update B with binding constraints of this link. If aj ∈/ A then
    A ←− A ∪ { a j } .
    Update≺witha0 ≺aj andaj ≺a∞.
    agenda←−agenda∪{(aj,pj)|pj ∈preconds(aj)}. pi
    π ←− RESOLVE-THREATS(π, aj, ⟨aj −→ ai⟩). Return POP1(π, agenda).

Comment: Can you share your code, so we can help you better?

Comment: i don't know how to start ?! this is the algorithm of partial ordered planning in artificial intelligence